# What is this objective-c syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, bitwise-operators

What is the caret (^) for here and what is it doing ?

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
  return [self.name hash] ^ [self.birthday hash];
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: Seems unfair that I get voted down because I failed to find the duplicate question myself.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote you

Comment: I didn't downvote you, however I don't think it was unfair.  It's in the C language specification and you can plainly see it's an operator.

Comment: @BenKane You suggest that this is a duplicate of a question where the caret has to do with blocks, but this isn't for blocks.

Comment: @Gavin Maybe..the question is literally "What does the caret in objective C mean?" though, and the answer there points out XOR.

Comment: I guess it is not technically a duplicate. Close enough in my opinion

Comment: @BenKane The code sample in that question is clearly showing the caret used in block syntax.

Comment: @Droppy 'plainly see' and 'obvious' is just unhelpful

Comment: @robdashnash Well this isn't a tutorial site.  If it wasn't obvious to you that it's an operator then you need to do more study.

Comment: @Gavin Ok fair enough

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise exclusive OR. It's not Objective-C, it's just plain old C. It compares the bits of both items you give it and returns a value with 1s for only the bits that are 1 in one of the items but not the other.

If you have two numbers:

```
5  (00000101)
11 (00001011)
```

The bitwise exclusive OR will yield the result:

```
14 (00001110)
```

Comment: "items"?  Can you be a bit (get it) more specific?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bitwise XOR operation. In other words, this code is trying to return true if one of the expressions is true, but not both.
I would code it this way:

```
BOOL nameHash = ...;
BOOL birthdayHash = ...;
if(nameHash && !birthdayHash) return TRUE;
if(!nameHash && birthdayHash) return TRUE;
return FALSE;
```

Let the compiler do the clever optimization work. The code above is clear and readable. Being verbose is only bad if it obscures the code.

Comment: Like you said it's bitwise XOR. It's not bool xor, it not return true. It return bitwise XOR.